# Linear transformation surjective and/ or injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am new to linear algebra, and would like some feedback regarding the following answer to a textbook question:

> Let $T:M_{2\times 3}(\mathbb R) \to M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$ be a linear
>   transformation. Answer the following two questions:
>
> 1. Is it possible for T to be surjective?
> 2. Is it possible for T to be injective?

My answer is the following:

1. Yes, because it is possible for each element in $M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$ to be the result of linear transformation $T$ applied to $M_{2\times 3}(\mathbb R)$.
2. No, because there are more rows in $M_{3\times 3}(\mathbf R)$ than in $M_{2\times 3}(\mathbf R)$, and therefore the elements in $M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)$ cannot be the exclusive result of the elements in $M_{2\times3}(\mathbb R)$.

I have no idea whether I am on the right track?

Thank you!

Comment: @DietrichBurde criticism accepted, but can you give me a hint as to how to go about 1 and how to redefine 2?

Comment: Vector spaces of matrices can be confusing because the vectors are the matrices. Notice that a two-by-three matrix is equivalent to a $6$-dimensional vector because it is described by $6$ real numbers. Change the problem to $T:\mathbb R^6\to\mathbb R^9$ and then try to answer the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* 
For 1. use the rank-nullity theorem for $T$.

For 2. consider the embedding of $M_{2,3}(K)$ into $M_{3,3}(K)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A:U\to V$ be a linear operator between finite-dimensional vector spaces $U$ and $V$.

**(1)** $\text{rank}(A)\leq\text{dim}(V)$.

**(2)** $\text{rank}(A)+\text{nullity}(A)=\text{dim}(U)$.

**(3)** $A$ is injective iff $\text{nullity}(A)=0$.

**(4)** $A$ is surjective iff $\text{rank}(A)=\text{dim}(V)$

**(5)** The dimension of $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is $mn$.

That is more than enough to answer both questions.

Comment: Right, which is why I used a different symbol to denote an arbitrary linear operator between $U$ and $V$

Comment: Ordinarily I would agree, but $T$ was already taken.  It would be like fixing $n=4$ and then trying to use the notation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ or something.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just want to check that I got this right, because the answer it leads to is the opposite of what I had originally thought: according to the above, if A is surjective, then rank(A)=9, but rank(A)+nullity(A)=dim(U), giving 9+nullity(A)=6, which is impossible: so A cannot be surjective. However, if A is injective, Rank A = 6 (because dimKerT = 0), which is indeed less than 9, so there is no contradiction, and A can be injective… Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: You have the first part right.  But for the second part, merely showing that it doesn't contradict the rank-nullity theorem isn't enough. You have to actually exhibit some kind of example, even if it's not explicit.  For example, let $\{u_1,\cdots,u_6\}$ be a basis for $M_{2\times 3}$ and $\{v_1,\cdots,v_9\}$ a basis for $M_{3\times 3}$.  Then define $T$ by the rule $T(u_i)=v_i$ for $i=1,\cdots 6$.

Comment: and the remaining $v_7-v_9$ are simply unrelated to $M_{2x3}$?

Comment: Correct.  They are not part of the image of $T$.

Comment: Perect, I got it now! Thank you so much...